# Preventing excessive rerendering when using mapbox and react context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mapbox, viewport

I have an application that uses a mapbox map and I am trying to allow for an adjustment of the viewport from another, separate card component. The way I went about this was creating a viewport context and passing the viewport and the function that sets it to both the map and the card component.

This works, but I'm running into an issue with rerendering. Whenever the user is scrolling around on the map, the viewport is constantly changing and thus everything inside the Viewport Provider is constantly rerendering. A simplified version of the code is below

App

```
<ViewportProvider>
   *Container that holds both the map and the sidebar that renders the card components*
</ViewportProvider>
```

ViewportProvider

```
import React from "react";
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  longitude: 15,
  latitude: 25,
  zoom: 1

};

export const ViewportContext = React.createContext();

export const ViewportProvider = (props) => {
  const [viewport, setViewport] = React.useState(INITIAL_STATE);


  return (
    <ViewportContext.Provider
      value={{
        viewport,
        setViewport,
      }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}
```

Map

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import ReactMapGL from "react-map-gl";
import { ViewportContext } from "./ViewportProvider";

const { viewport, setViewport } = useContext(ViewportContext);

<Map onViewportChange={nextViewport => setViewport(nextViewport)} {...viewport}/>
```

Card

```
const {setViewport} = useContext(ViewportContext)

<Card onClick={setViewport(...newValue)}/>
```

How can I stop the excessive rerendering when the user is moving around the map without losing the ability for the user to adjust the viewport from the card component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By putting `viewport` and `setViewport` in the same context, you are forcing the sidebar to re-render each time the viewport changes, because it uses `useContext(ViewportContext)` — even though it only uses the `setViewport` part of the context. There are a few options:

- Reduce the performance impact of re-rendering by simply moving `useContext(ViewportContext)` into a sub-component, so that only the sub-component, not the whole sidebar, renders whenever the viewport is updated.
- If you only need one-way updates (sidebar button can set the map's viewport, but no other components need to know when the user moves around the map), then you could remove the setViewport call from the map.
- Put `viewport` and `setViewport` in separate contexts. This would mean two `createContext()` calls, but you would still keep a single ViewportProvider component that renders both providers, e.g. `const [viewport, setViewport] = useState(); return <Context1.Provider value={viewport}><Context2.Provider value={setViewport}> ...`. Then, your sidebar can `useContext` only for the context it needs, and will not re-render when the other one changes.
- Use something like [`useContextSelector`](https://github.com/dai-shi/use-context-selector) to replace `const {setViewport} = useContext(ViewportContext)` with `const setViewport = useContextSelector(ViewportContext, (ctx) => ctx.setViewport)`.
- If you're considering broader architectural changes, libraries like [React Redux](https://react-redux.js.org) or [Recoil](https://recoiljs.org/docs/introduction/core-concepts) could provide alternative designs that would avoid this problem.

(By the way, in your code as written, I would recommend you wrap the `value` you pass to `ViewportContext.Provider` in a `useMemo(() => ({viewport, setViewport}), [viewport, setViewport])`, so that it doesn't trigger an update when the ViewportProvider is re-rendered if the viewport hasn't changed.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will give these options a try at work tomorrow and see what i can do.

Unfortunately, adding a library like Redux or Recoil isn't really an option (we actually just moved away from a dedicated state management library) for such little client side state

Comment: Yep, I understand, our project is similar. `useContextSelector` might be the most straightforward solution that gives you the best of both redux-style "selectors" and React Context providers. We implemented a [custom version](https://github.com/foxglove/studio/blob/main/packages/studio-base/src/util/createSelectableContext.tsx) before that library was around but it basically works the same way.